# BIRT report with two or three-deep nested tables from POJO datasource

Tags: java, eclipse, nested, reporting, birt

I need to produce some on-demand reports in Java from data that comes from various sources, mostly from synchronous transactions against a mainframe so there is no database backend thus no SQL available.
I'll have the data as a structure of nested java objects as illustrated in this diagram:

```
                     +-----------+
                 __/_|Accounts   |______________
                |  \ |           |              |
                |    +-----------+             /|\
 +---------+    |                          +------------+
 |Customers|____|                          |Transactions|
 |         |    |                          |            |
 |         |    |                          +------------+
 +---------+    |    +-----------+             \|/
                |__/_|Investments|______________|
                   \ |           |
                     +-----------+
```

Customer has some basic type fields such as id, name, address, etc and optionally one or two lists of Account or Investment objects which in turn also have basic type fields suchs id, name, balance, etc and a list of Transaction objects... you get the idea.

One report would list for example, a customer's details and all his/her accounts and investments with their balance and latest transactions.

I've been exploring BIRT with POJO data sources but I'm not able to find any examples that handle two or three-deep nested tables/lists. The examples in the BIRT tutorial and actuate.com don't seem to deal with this situation, they only work with lists of simple objects so I'm not sure this can be done using POJO datasources.

Can anyone point me to a a suitable example or suggest an alternative solution?

.

---

PD.
Some docs I've read:

- http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.3.php#jump_3
- http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/29933-nested-tables-using-pojo-oda-ds/
- http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/27311-nested-pojo-and-scripted-datasource/
- http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31151-how-to-access-nested-collection-and-render-in-list/

Comment: This article is very helpful: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.de/2013/03/nested-data-sets-with-input-parameters.html